# SHACL Rule Condition doesn't seem to get executed before rule execution

Tags: rdf, shacl

I'm using the Apacha Java Jena engine.

I want to derive a ex:hasFather relationship by going through all instances of <Man> and then seeing if they are the subject of a ex:hasChild relationship. This would be my NodeShape to derive it. I know that I could target <Man> in the first place, but let's say it want to to it this way. Using the Jena engine the condition doesn't seem to take effect, it still targets <Woman> aswell, leading to wrong ex:hasFather triples. According to documentation the condition should be executed before the rule itself gets executed.

```
<ParentsShape> a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass <Person> ;
  sh:rule [
   a sh:TripleRule ;
   sh:subject [ sh:path  :hasChild ] ;
   sh:predicate :hasFather ;
   sh:object sh:this ;
   sh:condition [
    sh:targetClass <Man> ;
   ]
  ] .
```

How would I have to rewrite my sh:condition in order for it to work?

Comment: Does Apache Jena even support sh:rule? It is implemented by the TopBraid SHACL API. Are you using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `sh:targetClass` is only used for selecting focus nodes, not for checking that a node is of a certain class. For that `sh:class` needs to be used. Replacing that part, I was able to derive the relationship.